# Can't connect lightning aura component with Google tag manager

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, csp, tag-manager

I have a lightning component which I'm trying to connect with Tag Manager. 
I followed the instructions in the tag manager page, first saved the js code as a static resource
[image: Js in tag manager page]

then called that script with the ltng:require tag

[image: tag]

pasted the iFrame tag, obviously without the noscript around it because lightning doesn't support noscript tag

[image: iFrame tag]

but when I activate the preview mode in Tag Manager and reload the page nothing happens and in the
console this error appears

[image: error]

I've tried to solve this issue adding https://www.googletagmanager.com to the CSP trusted sites
such as described in this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5

also downgraded the lightning component api version in order to disable lightning locker for
the component https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_ls_disable.htm

and disabled stricter CSP restrictions https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp_stricter.htm

but the error still occurs do you have any idea or is there something am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please make an [edit] to include code and error messages as text, not images. Use the `{}` tool in the editor to format code inclusions

Comment: Check this article, may be it can be helpful:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/04/google-tag-manager-for-community-cloud.html

Comment: David thanks for your suggestion is so much appreciated and also thanks Matías but I checked the article I'll try to adapt it for lightning